# Group for nonusers

Tags: sharepoint-online

Using Office 365, SharePoint - I have a form that the user will be able to select shop personnel from a drop down box - my problem is I have a signature field that is tied to the drop down box but it won't recognize the name in the box because the names are not part of a SharePoint group or our directory.  Is there anyway to create a SharePoint group for the shop personnel (they are not active users and will not be - manufacturing company and the shop does not have access to computers) without having to setup accounts for all 400? The shop personnel will use our SharePoint users ipads to sign the form.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to tell what your exact requirements are, but might I suggest creating an unlicensed ('guest'/ 'external'/ 'Shop Staff') account and using that as your group and just have an optional text field for them to fill in their name so that you can identify them?

Comment: The problem is the app we're using for forms, the signature field only recognizes people in groups/users from SharePoint.  Even if we setup an account such as the above, it still won't recognize the employees. It seems to be a problem on the SharePoint side and Infowise side, but I cannot imagine that other businesses have not run into this issue for HR forms. Seems like Microsoft would allow you to create a group for employees that could be used in the lists.

Comment: Then you will probably have to set up individual accounts for each user on the site and add them to a specific group. Good news is you can probably automate that with powershell.